# Imprecise average at run time

Tags: c, average, precision

I am trying to solve a problem and I've run into a bit of an issue.
I have to find the running average of a series of numbers.
Example:

```
input 4 2 7 
output 4 3 4.3333
```

Now here's the problem although I get the answer, it is not the precise answer.

Accepted Output: [accuracy difference shown in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REO0W.png)

```
 290.6666666667
 385.4000000000
 487.8333333333
 477.4285714286
 496.4444444444
 ...
 523.8571166992
 506.0454406738
 495.3043518066
```

I can't find whats wrong.  Some help would be highly appreciated.

```
#include<stdio.h>

main(){
  int n;
  printf("set:");
  scanf("%d",&n);
  float arr[n+1],resarr[n+1];
  float sum=0;

  for(int i=1; i<=n; i++){
    scanf("%f",&arr[i]);
    sum=arr[i]+sum;

    float res= sum/(float)i;
    resarr[i]=res;
  }
  int i=1;
  while(i<=n) {
    printf("%0.10f\n",resarr[i]);
    i++;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You seem to have forgotten that array indexes are *zero based*. I.e. an array of `n` elements, have indexes from `0` to `n - 1` (inclusive).

Comment: And what have "max running time" (your title) to do with your problem?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude im sorry entirely my fault , i mean average at run time

Comment: You do know that `float` have a quite limited precision? What happens if you use `double` instead? Also, please read [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: That solved it, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
for(int i=1; i<=n; i++){ }
```

you are trying to access out of bound array elements, this certainly causes **undefined behavior** as let's assume if `n` is `5` then you are accessing `arr[5]` also which doesn't exist.

`C` doesn't perform array boundary condition check, its programmer responsibility to not to access out of bound elements else it causes UB.

In `C` array index starts from `0` not from `1`. So better start rotating loop from `0` to `n`. For e.g

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++) { 
   scanf("%f",&arr[i]);
   /* some code */
}
```

Comment: i'm using i to divide as well so instead of iterating 0 to n , i changed size of array to n+1
but my accuracy issue is still there

Comment: @pfn Well, nothing prevents you from using the more idiomatic range and then calculate the average as  `double avg = (double)sum / (i + 1);`

Comment: "you are trying to access out of bound array elements," --> No.  code is not accessing outside the array `arr[i]` as it was defined with `arr[n+1]`.

Comment: @Bob__ Casting `sum` is insufficient as the running sum saved  also needs to be `double sum` to insure precision with `sum=arr[i]+sum;`.

Answer (score 0):

Code fails to achieve the desired accuracy as it is using `float` rather  than `double`. [@Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54050429/average-at-run-time/54053215#comment94938210_54050429)

Typical [`float`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) is precise to 1 part in 2<sup>23</sup>.  For printing to `0.0000000001`, better to use `double` which is [typically precise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) to 1 part in 2<sup>53</sup>.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  //float arr[n + 1], resarr[n + 1];
  //float sum = 0;
  double arr[n + 1], resarr[n + 1];
  double sum = 0;
  ...

    // scanf("%f", &arr[i]);
    scanf("%lf", &arr[i]);

    ...
    // float res = sum / (float) i;
    double res = sum / i;  // cast not needed as `sum` is `double`
  ...
}
```

---

Iterating from 1 is not idiomatic in C.  More common to iterate starting at 0.

`size_t` is best for array sizing and indexing.  `int` may be too narrow.  Of course with small arrays, it makes scant difference.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  printf("set:");
  size_t n;
  scanf("%zu", &n);
  double arr[n], resarr[n];
  double sum = 0;

  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    scanf("%lf", &arr[i]);
    sum = arr[i] + sum;

    double res = sum / (i+1);
    resarr[i] = res;
  }

  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf("%0.10f\n", resarr[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

---

More robust code would check the input from the user it insure it is valid, allocate rather than use a VLA if `n` is allowed to be large, flush output before reading, etc.

Note that array `arr[]` is not needed, just a single `double` for the input and `sum`.